# Jquery UI Autocomplete not working with Jquery modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jquery.autocomplet.js plugin in my application and facing same problem as i can not use the up and down arrow keys for selecting results from autocomplete list. What can i do to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance

This is my code

```
 $("#CityName").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "../api/Bind/GetCities?autoCompleteText=" + request.term,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.SuggestionID,
                            value: item.SuggestionName
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            getStateZip(ui.item.id);
            $("#CityName")[0].defaultValue = ui.item.value;
            isSelected = true;
        }
```

Comment: Could you post a fiddle without the ajax part ? or expand on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/ggGKf/), because from looking at your code i don't see what could be causing the problem

Comment: Make sure you're using one of the latest versions and you've linked the right css theme.